# single validation message in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs, i have null validation when i try to submit my form it prevents me from submitting if it is blank but my problem is it shows message for every feild. Suppose out of 5 feilds 3 are blank it will show 3 different messages, i just want a single message to be shown. I know i have different messages for each but when i try to add a single message the form submits even if it is blank.

Code :

```
const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);
const { kookId, kookName, dishName,  cusine, foodType, spicyLevel, serving, price, description 
} = data;
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

const validate = () => {
let errors = {};
if (!kookId) {
  errors.kookId = alert("Kook Id is Required");
}
if (!kookName) {
  errors.kookName = alert("Kook Name is Required");
}
if (!dishName) {
  errors.dishName = alert("Dish Name is Required");
}
if (!cusine) {
  errors.cusine = alert("Cusine is Required");
}
if (!foodType) {
  errors.foodType = alert("Food Type is Required");
}
if (!price) {
  errors.price = alert("Price is Required");
}
if (!description) {
  errors.description = alert("Description is Required");
}
if (!file) {
  errors.file = alert("File is Required");
}
return errors;

};

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let errors = validate();
if (Object.keys(errors).length) return setErrors(errors);
setIsSubmit(true);
if (!id) {
  try {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "masterMenu"), {
      ...data,
  
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
alert("Form Submitted Successfully!!!") 
navigate("/account");
```

};

Comment: `alert` returns undefined and state is immutable; use `setErrors` rather than `errors.foo = ...`.

Comment: i m afraid, i didn't get you

Comment: You might want to read a basic React tutorial or the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly. It says "Do Not Modify State Directly.
For example, this will not re-render a component: `this.state.comment = 'Hello'; // Wrong`". `alert()` always returns undefined, so your object will be empty. You probably want these to be plain strings rather than `alert()` calls.

Comment: Great. Feel free to add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help future visitors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (
  !data.kookId,
  !data.kookName,
  !data.dishName,
  !data.cusine,
  !data.foodType,
  !data.price,
  !data.description
   ) {
  alert("Please fill out all fields")
  return
}

else
setIsSubmit(true);
if (!id) {
  try {
    await addDoc(collection(db, "masterMenu"), {
      ...data,
  
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
alert("Form Submitted Successfully!!!") 
navigate("/account");
};
```

Comment: This still looks pretty strange. Can you explain how it works, why it's a good solution and show a full component example? Thanks.

Comment: It's good because of it's simplicity, here we check if all the feilds are blank or not and even if one or three feilds are blank it prompts the user just once to check and fill alll the feilds instead of one message for each feild., For example, i followed this repo https://github.com/TylerPottsDev/yt-reactjs-firebase-recipe-app/blob/master/src/App.js.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).